# How to ask "how often" in French?

Tags: questions, pronoms-interrogatifs

I know how to ask "how many times per [time period]", or "at which frequency", but what is the non-scientific way to ask "how often"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the expression [tous les combien](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/combien/17380/locution?q=combien#160869):

> Tous les combien, interroge sur la fréquence : L'autobus passe tous
>   les combien ?

Note there is no *s* at the end of *combien* since the latter is an invariable noun (masculine):

> Le combien (nom masculin invariable), indique le quantième du mois, le rang : Le combien
>   sommes-nous ? Le combien est-il au classement ?

Comment: While "tous les combien" should be understood in Canada I feel it's most probably only used in some countries.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I heard it many times in France (Paris): I am pretty sure that most people (like 99% or more) there understand the expression. No idea about other French-speaking countries.

Comment: When I said "in some countries" I specifically meant France but thought maybe some other french-speaking countries use it too. I've noticed that the french spoken in some african countries is close to how it is used in France, especially in regions where arab is also used.

Comment: I myself never heard that expression. Though it is rather common for me to say or hear `L'autobus passe à tous les combien de temps?` (more complete version of the expression)

Comment: @Sifu Interesting! `à tous les combien de temps?` would sound a bit weird in Paris. I guess it has regional variations.

Comment: Très intéressant, j'avais jamais vu le mot "combien" être utilisé de cette manière

Answer (score 16):

There is no good direct translation I can think of, one would rather say “are you doing it often” and depending on the answer ask further “at which frequency”.

> Allez-vous souvent à la piscine? (Are you often going to the swimming pool?)
>   Oui, régulièrement (Yes regularly)
>   Ah oui? À quelle fréquence ? (Really? How often?)
>   Deux fois par semaine (Twice a week)

Comment: "À quelle fréquence" would be my choice here. I do not think there is any real other choice.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative might be "Tu fais X combien de fois par semaine/mois/an...?" "How often do you go swimming". You must choose somewhere between weeks and years (for example)… which might lead to confusion:

> Q: Tu vas à la piscine combien de fois par semaine?
>   A: Ça va pas, non? J'ai *horreur* de ça — j'y vais une fois par an maximum.

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is really old but I am not convinced by the actual answers so I'll just give mine.
In my opinion the only acceptable answer to this question has been given by [Oneira](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11410/635):

I would say “À quelle fréquence ?” in French.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with the "tous les combien". Never heard of that in France, except when used with a unit appended such as "tous les combien DE MINUTES" or "tous les combien DE TEMPS".

However I heard "tous les quand" a lot, as in "le bus passe tous les quand?". This is informal, obviously.

Comment: I'm quite surprised about your experience. ***Tous les combien*** without any unit appended is a well known and used expression in France. It is documented in Le bon usage, the TLFi, the Larousse and the Robert, to name a few. On the other hand, ***tous les quand***, while not unused seems to me much rarer.